# Cannot delete objects in other context

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am facing this problem consistently for over 3 months. I have searched a lot and read related docs and visited many forums but couldn't find working solution. I am getting typical NSManagedObject error while deleting objects. ***An NSManagedObjectContext cannot delete objects in other contexts.***

I tried to go around and tried to delete object using its NSManagedObject ID but to no avail.

```
  NSManagedObjectID *findingsSurveyDataItemApiId = [findingsSurveyDataItemApi objectID];
            [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.managedObjectContext objectWithID:findingsSurveyDataItemApiId]];
```

Can anyone tell why is above solution still not working?

PS: I have two managed object context in the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it might be a misleading error message from Core Data. If the object you want to delete has not yet been saved to the persistent store, `objectWithID` will not return a valid object, according to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/objectWithID:):

> The data in the persistent store represented by objectID is assumed to exist—if it does not, the returned object throws an exception when you access any property (that is, when the fault is fired).

Use `existingObjectWithID:error:` instead and check if it returns a non-nil object before trying to delete it.

Comment: Sounds convincing, will give it a shot with check for temporary id `BOOL isTemporary = [[managedObject objectID] isTemporaryID];`